# Get output from fzf in the terminal without executing it

Tags: bash, terminal, fzf

fzf rocks! I want to use it to search bash history. When a match is found, I want it to be placed on the command line, but ***not*** executed so I can edit it further. (All of this is in a sourced bash function or script so it has access to my history.)

I have it almost working, but not quite.

This selects the command, but runs it immediately:

```
eval $(history | "$HOME/bin/fzf" +s | sed 's/ *[0-9]* *//')
```

This gets it into my clipboard, but when I paste it, it still ends with a blank and a newline so it executes immediately.

```
history | "$HOME/bin/fzf" +s | sed 's/ *[0-9]* *//' | xclip -se c
```

I also tried a couple of variations including

```
history | "$HOME/bin/fzf" +s | sed -e 's/ *[0-9]* *//' -e 's/$//' | xclip -se c
```

with the same result.

This actually works, but I still have to put it in the clipboard and then manually paste it.

```
history | "$HOME/bin/fzf" +s | sed -re 's/ *[0-9]* *//' | awk '{printf "%s", $0}' | xclip -se c
```

How can I do this in one step - without a manual paste?

I thought just leaving off the xclip would do it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using a reverse search for this (Ctrl and r) ?

Comment: I never got used to using that. I just tried it. fzf is a lot nicer. It lets me see many alternatives at once with lots more searching options, not just one at a time. And, I didn't see a way to edit what I found. When I pressed Enter, it just ran the unmodified command. Also, if I can figure this out, it might open other possibilities for automatically getting things on the command line for me to work with.

Comment: You can press Ctrl-r multiple times to go through the different options related to the text entered. Then you can press escape to get the command on your command line to edit. I would suggest spending time studying the options already available before spending time attempting to design your own

Comment: Also, it you want all the different options relating to the search displayed on screen, you could simply use history and pipe it through grep to search. You can then use !<command line number> to action the command

Comment: @RamanSailopal Those are good suggestions. I haven't done much with history other than using the up-arrow to go back. Occasionally, I try an ! followed by some characters, but that's dangerous because it runs it before you see if it selected what you thought it would. Still, fzf appears to be pretty popular, so I am not the only one who finds value in it. Also, these are tools that require a couple of lines of code to implement. I'm not writing my own text editor or a new version of mencoder.

Answer (score 2):

**fzf** comes ready to install this functionality in [fzf's key-bindings.bash](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.bash) mentioned by @sudavid4. The `__fzf_history__` function searches bash history interactively using fzf.

In default history handling (though unnecessary with fzf's function), editing after selection is enabled by setting `histverify`. From `man bash`:

> histverify
>
> If set, and readline is being used, the results of history substitution are not immediately passed to the  shell parser.  Instead, the resulting line is loaded into the readline editing buffer, allowing further modification.

Finally, bash's builtin `fc` (learn more with `help`, not `man`), supports "Display[ing] or execut[ing] commands from the history list" in addition to the `history` builtin which focuses on "Display or manipulat[ion of] the history list."

---

#### Note also...

[fzf's key-bind.bash](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.bash) snippet:

```
  # CTRL-R - Paste the selected command from history into the command line
  bind -m emacs-standard -x '"\C-r": __fzf_history__'
  bind -m vi-command -x '"\C-r": __fzf_history__'
  bind -m vi-insert -x '"\C-r": __fzf_history__'
```

A neighboring bash shopt (shell option) with related but different purpose:

> histreedit
>
> If set, and readline is being used, a user is given the opportunity to re-edit a failed history substitution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but using https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391679/how-to-automatically-insert-a-string-after-the-prompt
gives the answer for zsh

```
print -z $(history |sed -re 's/ *[0-9]* *//'|fzf --tac --no-sort)
```

Did not try with bash.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that junegunn already solved this problem for you. [In this file](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.bash) he replaces the bash ctrl-r with exactly the functionality you are after. I did have a small problem sourcing this file because of the line `fzf-file-widget` outputing ``` sh: ``fzf-file-widget': not a valid identifier ```, but after changing that for `fzf_file_widget` it works great.

Comment: Can you please show an example of how should we use it? I'm using it like this `alias scripts=ls ~/dotfiles/scripts | sed -e 's/\..*$//' | fzf-file-widget` but I'm getting an error  `"fzf-file-widget:zle:4: widgets can only be called when ZLE is active"`

Answer (score 0):

In the current fzf version, `ctrl-r` behaves exactly like what you want. From [the readme](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#key-bindings-for-command-line):

> `CTRL-R` - Paste the selected command from history onto the command-line

In fact, now [some people want](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/pull/1492) [the other way around](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73892748/9157799).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize this never got fully answered. I ended up writing a function which is in $HOME/.bashrc.

It still requires pressing paste (Ctrl+Shift+v) to get the result on the command line.

```
# fh - repeat history
fh () 
{ 
    history | tac | "$HOME/bin/fzf" +s | sed -re 's/ *[0-9]* *//' | awk '{printf "%s", $0}' | xclip -se c
}
```

It leaves the selected command line in the clipboard so you can paste it into the command line for further editing and execution.

It pipes the CLI history into `tac` which reverses the order so the most recent commands show up first (at the end) and sends it on to `fzf`. The `+s` tells `fzf` not to sort the output again. Next, `sed` is used to strip off the command number prefix from the result. It then goes through `awk` to strip the trailing newline from the command so it won't run as soon as it is pasted. Finally, `xclip` is used to put the selection into the clipboard.

For the final touch, I add

```
bind '"\C-F":" fh\n"'  # fzf history on ctrl+F
```

to `.bashrc` to bind the function to `Ctrl+f` to make it easy to use and remember.

I added a leading space to the bound `fh` command so that it isn't added to command history when it is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this behaviour for opening files (not history) via fzf.

Checking the link shared by @mcint: [fzf's key-bind.bash](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.bash) helped me solve my usecase:

> CTRL-T: Paste the selected file path into the command line.
>
> E.g. vim CTRL-T

By using this method, command with expanded filename shows up in bash history.

Answer (score 0):

I just added this to my .bashrc.

It executs whatever fzf outputs immediately. Not a solution to the question, but may be useful to someone else.

`` alias fuz='history | fzf --tac --no-sort | `sed s/^\ [0-9]*\ \ //`' ``