# Execute highlighted command with single keypress in fzf

Tags: command-line, fzf

I'm using `fzf` <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> binding to navigate the command line history. Now first <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress selects the command, and the second one executes it.

Is it possible to configure `fzf` to perform both of these actions with a single keypress?